# How to convert IEnumerable<string> to IList<string> in Dictionary?

Tags: c#

I have a method that contains `IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> collection` as parameter

```
void find(IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> collection)
{
    // I need to remove some values, like this

      collection[element].Remove(element[element.Count - 1]);
  }
```

How to convert this parameter to some state when I can remove some elements?

Comment: Why does a method `find` remove elements? Is it actually an `IList<string>`? Then you can try-cast it. If it succeeds use `list.Remove` otherwise create a new list, then replace the old with the new.

Comment: What's `element`?  What's `serviceDependence`? What are you trying to do?  What have you tried that doesn't work?

Comment: @CharlesMager sorry, edit the code

Comment: If you want something that you can remove from, don't use `IEnumerable`.

Comment: As `IEnumerable` is just an abstraction over iterating a source, you can just insert a new `IEnumerable` that was built from a LINQ statement that omits the thing you want to skip: `collection[element] = collection[element].Except(new [] { value });` Though this depends on lots of other factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is something like this: if the value of the `Dictionary<,>` is an `IList<>`, then you can `RemoveAt` directly, otherwise convert it to an `IList<>`, remove the element and replace the collection in the `Dictionary<,>`

```
void find(IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> collection, string element)
{
    // I need to remove some values, like this

    IEnumerable<string> value = collection[element];

    IList<string> ilist = value as IList<string>;

    if (ilist != null && !(value is string[]))
    {
        // Remove the last element
        ilist.RemoveAt(ilist.Count - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        ilist = value.ToList();

        ilist.RemoveAt(ilist.Count - 1);

        collection[element] = ilist;
    }
}
```

**WARNING**

The working of this method is a little schizophrenic. If someone had saved a reference to one of the `IEnumerable<>` before the `find` was called, after the `find` that reference could be to the same or to a different collection than the one present in the `Dictionary<,>` (it depends if the `find` had to recreate it or if it could reuse it).

An example:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
{
    { "Foo", new string[] { "Foo1", "Foo2" } },
};

var lst1 = dict["Foo"];

find(dict, "Foo");

var lst2 = dict["Foo"]; // lst1 and lst2 reference DIFFERENT collections

find(dict, "Foo");

var lst3 = dict["Foo"]; // lst2 and lst3 reference THE SAME collection
```

and

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
{
    { "Foo", new List<string> { "Foo1", "Foo2" } },
};

var lst1 = dict["Foo"];

find(dict, "Foo");

var lst2 = dict["Foo"]; // lst1 and lst2 reference THE SAME collection

find(dict, "Foo");

var lst3 = dict["Foo"]; // lst2 and lst3 reference THE SAME collection
```

Comment: double semicolon at the end of `collection[element]`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Still legal :-)

Comment: That itches my OCD. Be kind ;P

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Mine too :-)